# Get pixels coordinates above a threshold in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a gray image (648*488 pixels) and I want to get the coordinates of the pixels above a threshold, I need to be really fast doing this so I want to know if there is a function in opencv to do this.

Answer (score -2):

You could start with the OpenCV forEach method in the Mat class.
It uses one of several parallel frameworks for multithreading.

If it has to be even faster, access the memory directly and compute the threshold for several pixels with SIMD instructions at the same time.

You can also use GPUs (Cuda / OpenCL).